# Unable to log into phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

setting up a phpMyAdmin database for my works website but I'm unable to log into mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin.

I've set in the config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

I've also tried setting AllowNoPassword to false and giving it a password but that also doesn't work.

I've looked into other questions like this and seen many answers that username = "root" and password is null as default (and a few other answers like admin and password) and non of those have worked.

I'm curious if I missed a step in setting up phpMyAdmin? I installed the latest version, unzip'd it into my websites directory, setup the config.inc.php file and uploaded it to my server.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: your db has no password on the root account? that's incredibly bad...

Comment: I'm planning on changing the default login information once I've actually logged on, but am unable to do as at the moment as I cannot log in.

Comment: what error or message are you getting? and i am not sure how `$i` is set in the phpmyadmin config file.

Comment: Cannot log in to the MySQL server - This is the error I'm getting

Comment: Please post the exact error message, 'cannot login' might be because the port isn't open on the remote server.  Agreed with MarcB, root with no password on a public server is a security hole the size of gargantua.

Comment: That is the only error displaying on screen after trying to log in, so I'm not sure what you mean by "exact error". Also I've already responded to MarcB, I'll be changing the login info once I'm able to actually login I'm obviously not going to leave it password-less on a public server.... (Also phpMyAdmin defaults to root and no password to start with which is why its setup that way atm)

Comment: It sounds as if you've just set up MySQL as well, correct? You'll have to use whatever ID/pwd was set up for that MySQL server to log in -- at least until more users are created. Can you log into the MySQL server without using phpMyAdmin? If not, that's the first step in solving this problem.

Comment: @mrunion Yes I've just setup MySQL as well. I've tried logging on to mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin with my MySQL login info and that too doesn't work. When I open the MySQL command line Clinet I can connect using my MySQL login info

Comment: @TimothyMcGee OK, good. Are TCP connections allowed to MySQL? Depending on what version you installed, it won't listen to network/TCP connections by default. Is MySQL running on the same server as phpMyAdmin? Check and make sure the host name conficgured for MySQL actually resolved to the MySQL instance you are trying to connect to (localhost, or 10.x.x.x, etc.).